# how to integrate node.js app (bpmn-js) in Java application (JSP)

Tags: java, node.js, jsp, bpmn

as the title says I'm trying to integrate a node.js application in a java website. Can this be accomplished without running the application in a dedicate node server? If yes, how? The specific application is bpmn-js, by bpmn.io.
thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'integrate'? There are few options you could use however not sure which would be best as I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to execute some nodejs in a jsp file, that's what i mean

Comment: Give samples of your node.js app and JSP

Comment: Ok, just to clarify -- you mean call into a Node.js application from Java code in the JSP? If so, then the simple way would be to invoke a service hosted in Node.js via a IP/port (e.g. call a REST service hosted in Node.js). You're talking cross-process communication here.